# Pervasive connection AutoCad VBA

Tags: vba, odbc, autocad, pervasive

I realize that this question has come up before, but none of the solutions I have found have an answer for my situation (at least none that I understand).

The situation is this:  I have a VBA macro which runs on top of AutoCad for several computers in a small office setting.  We recently introduced a new computer which only supports windows 10 (as opposed to windows 7, like the others).  As such, we also had to install a newer version of AutoCad, and it's been a couple of days of chasing down the bugs.

When the macro attempts to open a connection to our pervasive database on the "upgraded" computer, it throws this error

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

Here is my connection string

```
Driver={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface};ServerName=FILESERVER;dbq=@MYDATABASE;
```

I suspect that the trouble stems from the software attempting to use the 64 bit version of the Pervasive ODBC driver, but when I look in the 64 bit ODBC Data Source Administrator it's not installed (though there is a 32 bit driver installed)

All the computers have 64 bit versions of windows, and 64 bit versions of CAD, and only the 32 bit ODBC Pervasive driver, yet the new computer (running Windows 10) is the only one that throws this error.  It's my understanding that the newer version of AutoCad runs VBA7, where as the prior version used VBA6, so maybe that's why?

Is there a way to install a 64 bit version of the pervasive ODBC driver?  Or is there perhaps a ways to specify in the connection string to use the 32 bit driver?

Comment: What version of Pervasive are you using?  There are 64 bit ODBC drivers for later versions.  They can be downloaded at https://esd.actian.com/product/Zen_PSQL.  You'll need to download the client for the version of the Pervasive server you're using.  If you're using PSQL v11, you need the PSQL v11 client.  You can't use the v11 client with an older engine.

Comment: @mirtheil, how would I find out?  Pervasive control center version is 10.30.017, so does that mean I don't have v11?

Comment: If you're PCC is 10.30, you have PSQL V10 SP3.  You would have to upgrade (not free) to at least PSQL v11  and ideally PSQL v13 (current version as of Jan 2019) to get 64bit ODBC drivers.

Comment: All of that being said, it's the application that determines whether to use a 32 bit or 64 bit ODBC driver.  If the Autocad / VBA is 32 bit, you need a 32 bit driver.  If the application is 64 bit, you need the 64 bit ODBC.

Comment: @mirtheil Ok, looks like I may have to try a different type of connection.  I've used OLEDB from vb.net, maybe there's a library I can reference in VBA

Comment: Do you have PCC installed on the 'new' Windows 10 machine?  Does it connect to the database?  As far as OLEDB, there is not a 64 bit version the Pervasive OLEDB provider, even in newer versions.

Comment: I do have PCC installed, and it does connect to the database from some windows forms apps that are compiled as 32 bit. It's a bit corny, but maybe I'll have to write a small console app as a go-between.

Answer (score 0):

Just a crazy idea. you might use the script control for the database connections.
For 64 bit - a drop in replacement of the script control is availeable on github [Tablacus script control](https://github.com/tablacus/)

Mixing 64 bit and 32 bit isnt a great idea - in no case.
So you might write a small VBS script which just return the result you desire

```
Dim mConnection
Set mConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
mConnection.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=<IP zum Server>;Initial Catalog=        
<Datenbankname>","<Benutzername>","<Passwort>"
RESULT=mConnection.Execute "SELECT * FROM <tabelle>"
SetmConnection = Nothing
```

after the execution of the script you can now evaluate the script result.

sample using tablacus

```
Private Sub demo()
  Dim P1, sc
  ' Create an instance of the FileSystemObject.
  Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  ' Initialize scriptcontrol.
  Set sc = CreateObject("scriptcontrol")
  sc.LANGUAGE = "VBScript"
  sc.AllowUI = True
  sc.UseSafeSubset = True
  ' Add FileSystemObject to scriptcontrol
  sc.AddObject "FileSystem", fs, True
  ' Define the Scripting code
  P1 = "Sub Sub1" & vbNewLine & _
       " Dim Msg" & vbNewLine & _
       " Msg = ""You have """ & vbNewLine & _
       " Msg = Msg & FileSystem.Drives.Count" & vbNewLine & _
       " Msg = Msg & "" drives connected.""" & vbNewLine & _
       " MsgBox Msg" & vbNewLine & _
       "End Sub"
  ' Add the code
  sc.AddCode P1
  ' Run the code
  sc.RUN "Sub1"
End Sub

Sub JavaScript_in_VBA()
  'Go to Menu -> Tool -> References -> Microsoft Script Control 1.0 & Enable by Clicking it
  Dim jsObj As Object
  Set SCRIPT = CreateObject("scriptcontrol")

  Dim InputValue1 As Integer, InputValue2 As Integer, RESULT As Integer

  'Get Sample Parameters
  InputValue1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
  InputValue2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2)

  'Define Scripting Language
  jsObj.LANGUAGE = "JScript"
  With jsObj

    'Add JavaScript Code to Script Control Object
    .AddCode "function xProduct(a,b) {return (a*b);}"

    'Execute Added Script & Get result
    RESULT = .RUN("xProduct", InputValue1, InputValue2)
    'Result = .autocad.eval("xProduct( 1, 2)")

  End With
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 3) = RESULT
End Sub
```

you may also consider to use the scripting dictionary object whoch can be also passed between your vba code and the scriptcontrol
The tablacus API is identical with the MS script control. So you might use the MS documentation as well as there examples.

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing.  It's really hokey, but I wrote a console app to accept parameters and serve up the results to VBA.

Comment: Hm How about using VS.net and create a COM Dll. This extends vba nicely - even with the price to deal with .net. So you could get rid the console Application. There is also a way that the dll exports the functions automaticall. You will find a lot stuff which deals with strange interface things. In the templates of VB.net you will find already a predefined  COM.DLL . Thats how i extend Autocad if nothing else works. .NET is not that handy as VBA. So i implement just real missing things. :)

Comment: Ludweig  --I'm not that adept with programming (very much self taught).  These task just fall to me because I work in a small company.  You may as well have told me to reroute power to main conduit, because I have no idea what you're saying ;)

Comment: My first name is Thomas ;) And as like you i started in a small company by tasks like this 30 years ago ;) Anyhow  mixing 64 and 32 bit does not work well. And ODBC suxx by its poor performance in any case. So my suggestion is to change the database or the connector. If nothing helps use VB.NET and "adopt" a .net Connector for your purposes. That is not as hard as it sounds. Just a boring task. The benefit is a clean solution and usually way more speed. :) Try google for VB.NEt create COM.DLL . This COM.DLL (type of a dll noot the name)l can be referenced as VBA reference like usually.

Comment: @ Thomas Ludewig  - Thanks, I'l look into that!